# SQL query converting to LINQ

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I need to convert this T-SQL code into LINQ:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, Snippet, description, lat, lng, 
    (3959 * acos(cos(radians('1')) 
      * cos(radians(lat))
      * cos(radians(lng) 
      - radians('1'))
      + sin(radians('1'))
      * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance 
FROM 
    marker 
WHERE 
    (3959 * acos(cos(radians('1')) 
     * cos(radians(lat))
     * cos(radians(lng) 
     - radians('1'))
     + sin(radians('1'))
     * sin(radians(lat)))) < 50 
ORDER BY 
    distance;
```

I have tried to get *Linqer* to do this but I cant seem to set that up properly.

Any help would be great!

**Update**

```
Dim markers() = (tmp_Table _
                 .Select(x => new{ _
                    x.Id, _
                    x.Name,  _
                    x.Snippet, _
                    x.Description, _
                    x.Lat, _
                    x.Lng, _
                    Distance = (3959 * Math.acos(Math.cos(Math.PI)  _
                    * Math.cos(x.Lat) _
                    * Math.cos(x.Lng)  _
                    - Math.PI) _
                    + Math.sin(Math.PI) _
                    * Math.sin(Math.PI))) _
                 }) _
                 .Where(x >= x.Distance < 50)
```

Error on the line:

```
new{ _
```

Says:

> Type of 'With' expected.

Comment: you can have a having statement without groupby ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Not sure what all your values are, and what all the names of your columns are in your Linq environment.

Sorry I realized this was VB too late. I'm not very familiar with VB's syntax for linq, but this can help get you started at least.

Also my "radians" conversions might not be right, but this is the general strategy you should go for.

```
markers
.Select(x => new{
    x.Id,
    x.Name, 
    x.Snippet,
    x.Description,
    x.Lat,
    x.Lng,
    Distance = (3959 * Math.acos(Math.cos(Math.PI) 
   * Math.cos(x.Lat)
   * Math.cos(x.Lng) 
   - Math.PI)
   + Math.sin(Math.PI)
   * Math.sin(Math.PI)))
})
.Where(x => x.Distance < 50)
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to convert this to VB?

Comment: see MSDN for help with anonymous types in VB. Looks like it's `New With {` instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

Comment: also see MSDN for help with lambdas. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: VB.net .Where lambda would look like this:
.Where(Function(X) X.Distance <50)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starter query for you in VB.net.  Just add the missing properties:

```
Dim Markers = (from M in tmp_Table where M.Distance < 50 Select new With {.Id = M.id, .Name = M.Name, .Snippet = M.Snippet }).ToList()
```